# How to control file access in Windows?

Tags: go, file-permissions, chmod

Go provides [`os.Chmod()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chmod) for setting file and directory permissions. For example, if I want to ensure a file is accessible only to the current user, I can do the following:

```
os.Chmod("somefile.txt", 0600)
```

This works great on Linux but does absolutely nothing on Windows. After digging into the Go source code, I came across [its implementation](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L520). It seems like `S_IWRITE` is the only attribute supported.

How do I control access to a file or directory on Windows using Go?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Explanation

Windows does not use traditional Unix permissions. Instead, Windows controls access to files and directories through [access control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374860(v=vs.85).aspx). Each object has an [ACL (Access Control List)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx)<sup>*</sup> which controls access to the object.

Each ACL is basically a list of [ACEs (Access Control Entries)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa374868(v=vs.85).aspx) which determine what access a specific trustee (user, group, etc.) is granted. For example, a file may contain an ACE granting a specific user read access (`GENERIC_READ`) to the file.

Manipulating ACLs and ACEs is done through the [authorization functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375742(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows API.

<sub><sup>* technically each object has two ACLs - a DACL and a SACL</sup></sub>

#### Solution

Thankfully, learning all of these functions isn't necessary. I've put together [a small Go package named "go-acl"](https://github.com/hectane/go-acl) that does all of the heavy-lifting and exposes a function named (what else?) `Chmod`. Basic usage is as follows:

```
import "github.com/hectane/go-acl"

err := acl.Chmod("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt", 0755)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

#### Results

The `Chmod()` function creates three ACEs in the file's ACL:

[image]

- one for the owner (`WinCreatorOwnerSid`)
- one for the group (`WinCreatorGroupSid`)
- one for everyone else (`WinWorldSid`)